# I got my JSON, now I need it to download inot an specific directory

Tags: javascript, https, request

I have an API that periodically makes a request to RESTAPI and stores the data into my database, now I want to add a new feature for certain data: download some data by a request to my API, then, my API makes another request to the RESTAPI, but I dont want this data to store in my database I want it to download as JSON or CSV.

I managed to create the request, I coded the request to the RESTAPI and managed to get the JSON into a variable with all the data, Im stuck there, How do I make this data to get downloaded into a direcory?

Im using javascript **nodeJS** with **bent** ,**getJSON** ,**mssql** ,**https**.

the code of the function:

```
async function descargarDatosOpendata(anioIni, anioFin, Indicativo){
try{
while(anioIni == anioFin || anioIni < anioFin){
    console.log("first");
    var http = require("https");
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "hostname": "opendata.aemet.es",
        "path": "/opendata/api/valores/climatologicos/mensualesanuales/datos/anioini/"+ anioIni +"/aniofin/"+ anioIni +"/estacion/"+ Indicativo +"",
        "headers": {
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "api_key": "MYKEY"
        }
    };
    console.log("second");
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log("tercera");
        var chunks = [];
        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        res.on("end", async function () {       
            console.log("endChunk");
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            console.log(body);
            var bodyString = body.toString();
            bodyJSON = JSON.parse(bodyString);
            console.log(bodyJSON);
            console.log(bodyJSON.datos);
            if (bodyJSON.estado == 200 && bodyJSON.descripcion == "exito") {
                let obj = await getJSON(bodyJSON.datos);
                console.log(obj)
                        
            
            }
        });
    });
    anioIni++;
req.end();
}
} 
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

}

obj log is the data in json format: [{data}]

Comment: so, you want to know how to get a file and save it in nodejs?

Comment: Is this in Node or in the browser?

Comment: *How do I make this data to get downloaded into a direcory?* Is this a server or  a client download?

Comment: @MichaelFlores its nodeJS yea sorry didnt specify.

Comment: @Lain I would like it to be Client download

Comment: client download but the server makes the api request and generate the file ? in that case you will need to store the file an provide a download link to the client

Comment: @Lk77 maybe I messing up things, Since my server is making the request is consider the client now?

Comment: The server stays the server even if it act as a client on that api request

Comment: @Lk77 In that case, server download its the one, thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: then @MichaelFlores answer is the solution, you can append to a file that data, since you have an object, you either store it in json, or convert it in csv, the first options seems easier to me, and you can parse it if you need it back in a object form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is running in Node, you should use the Node `fs` module. The `appendFile` method will create a new file or append to it if it already exists. [Learn more about fs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-fs-module)

Example code

```js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile('mynewfile1.txt', 'Hello content!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I apreciate it.It works but in the file it appears as [object object] [object object] [object object]....  The data is not stored in the file, my guess is that I need to parse it somehow?  Any suggestion to this? thanks for you solution!

Comment: @Luisurrechaga it looks like you're writing the JSON object into the file and not the string representation.